# Custom TextArea - Colors enabled (for an html editor)

Tags: html, content-management-system, textarea, colors

I am looking for a tool/textarea that would provide a dreamweaver-like code area, or even notepad++, with code highlighting and intellisens, intelisens can be added afterward, but if its there its even better. The point is to add visual help to whoever is doing web editing with the component.

Is there any kind of tool that could do this job?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're interested, but have you tried looking into [Bespin](http://mozillalabs.com/bespin/) it seems to be a pretty well worked out online code editor.

Comment: this looks nice, however is there a javascript/.NET based solution?

Comment: It's a javascript solution for converting textarea's into syntax highlightable editor. I think you can use it with .Net, PHP, or whatever you'd like because it's a front-end extension.